# how to save macro code as vbs?

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know why I can't call my macro code from R, This is my code that I'm trying to save as vbs file: (should I save it in Notepad application?)

```
 Sub vb()
       Dim xlApp
       Dim xlBook
       Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
       Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("path.xlsm", 0, False)
       xlApp.Visible = True
       xlApp.Run "Countries"
       xlApp.Quit
       Set xlBook = Nothing
       Set xlApp = Nothing
 End Sub
```

How can I save the above code as vbs ?

Comment: This looks like valid VBScript to me (which also happens to be valid, but suboptimal, VBA). You can save it with Notepad too. What is the problem with it? The fact that you only define `Sub vb()` but don't execute it, so when you run this vbscript it does nothing?

Comment: Exactly how are you trying to run this from R?

Comment: @GSerg, the problem is that I export this code to .vbs file and when I double click on it, it gives an error (Type mismath: 'Attirbute').

Comment: @TimWilliams, the thing I'm trying to do is to save this code as a vbs file then use: shell(shQuote(normalizePath("vb.vbs" )), "r", flag = "/c") to run it by R.

Comment: You vbscript doesn't need to be in a sub - you can remove the first and last lines from your posted code.

Comment: @TimWilliams, oh your'e right, the notpad version is working now! But still the R is not running the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below VBS code as you cannot save VBA code as VBS as the schema or say they are not in the same page as C and C++ are different it is in the same way

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("path.xlsm")

objExcel.Application.Visible = True

objExcel.Application.Run "path.xlsm!Countries" 'Refer to the below if the code is under sheet
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

If you have placed the code in the sheet. user this line

```
objExcel.Application.Run "path.xlsm!sheet1.dog"
```

Hope this resolve your query. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 2):

You can export a code module from the project explorer, right-click on it and select `Export File...`.

You can also do it with VBA, i.e. to export "Module1":

```
With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1")
    .Export "c:\so\" & .Name & ".bas"
End With
```

Comment: Welcome back :)

Comment: @ShaiRado I was always around, watchin you :P

Comment: Thanks, I guess I got it.